# Password-protecting Django URL patterns in Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, gunicorn

I'm trying to password-protect a certain section of my Django site based on the URL. Say I've got the URL `/protected/section/` that I want to password-protect (the URL will also take URL parameters but I assume they will be processed after all this).

So I've added this to my Nginx config:

```
location /protected/section/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.demo.htpasswd;
}
```

And I've generated the `.htpasswd` file like this:

```
htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.demo.htpasswd demo
```

So now when I visit `http://mysite/protected/section/` I get the password prompt, but when I enter it I get a 404 error. Is there another line I need to add in order to get the request to be passed along to Django (via Gunicorn) like all other requests are? I thought after authentication the request would be treated as it would have been without the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

So, here are the relevant bits that worked for me in my `myapp.conf` file:

```
upstream appinstances {
  server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}

server {
  listen     80;
  server_name  myapp.example.com;
  location ^~/manage/ {
    satisfy any;
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  /etc/linotp2/admins;
    deny all;

    proxy_pass              http://appinstances;
    proxy_redirect          off;
  }
... # the rest of the config
}
```

I banged my head for a while on this. Hope it helps.